# Azure Education not working - please answer

Tags: azure, azureportal

I went to [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com),  logged in to my 365 education account and went to https://signup.azure.com/studentverification?offerType=1 and the message was:

*Unable to confirm your University ID

Sign in with a separate Microsoft Account

Please review the FAQ for eligibility and details.

Still have questions?*

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned during the sign-up process, you must get your academic status verified first.

> If your school is in our database, we will email you a verification
> link. ​Your school email address will be used only for verification
> purposes, for everything else please use you Microsoft account email.

Once verified, you can sign in using your Microsoft Account. In cases where verification isn't successful, reaching out to [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/) may be the only way forward.

In cases where you are unable to access or qualify for Azure for Students offer, you can consider signing up for an [Azure Free Account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/).

Comment: But I don't want to sign up for Azure Free Account, I need Azure Education.

Comment: @Voom Did you receive the verification link?

Comment: Which verification link?

Comment: @Voom ***If your school is in our database, we will email you a verification link.*** Please check your university mailbox for a verification link from MS. You should have gotten it if Microsoft recognizes your university domain.

Comment: I do not have a link in my mail.